# Convert linear-gradient syntax to -webkit-gradient syntax

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I am trying to add lines in the paragraph but I am unable to convert linear-gradient below syntax to -webkit-gradient syntax because linear-gradient is not supported in wicked_pdf for rails.

Any help, I am unable to find -webkit-gradient documentation on net.

```
linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(230, 230, 231, 1) 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it like this:

`-webkit-gradient(<type>, <point> [, <radius>]?, <point> [, <radius>]? [, <stop>]*)`

`<type>` is either linear or radial.

`<point>` is a pair of space-separated values. The syntax supports numbers, percentages or the keywords top, bottom, left and right for point values.

`[, <radius>]?` is a number and is only used when `<type>` is radial.

`<stop>` is a function, `color-stop`, `to`, or `from`. `color-stop` takes 2 arguments: the stop value (either a percentage or a number between 0 and 1.0), and a color (any valid CSS color). `to(color)` is the equaivalent of `color-stop(0, color)` and `from(color)` is the equaivalent of `color-stop(1.0, color)`.

Example: `-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00abeb), to(#fff), color-stop(0.5, #fff), color-stop(0.5, #66cc00))`

You can also use `-webkit-linear-gradient(angle, startColor, endColor)`

Example: `-webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, white, black)`

Your specific example will just be this:

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(230, 230, 231, 1) 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
```

Sources:

https://webkit.org/blog/175/introducing-css-gradients/

https://webkit.org/blog/1424/css3-gradients/